# Complex Circular Dependency among classes

Tags: c++, c++11

I have 5 classes  (A,B,C,D,E), each of which will have their own class and header files.

```
class A{};
class B
{
  B(A&a);
};
class C
{
  C(B&b);
};
class D:public A
{};
class E:public D
{
   vector<C*> vc;
};
```

Forward declaration will not work because I also have a lot of sharepointers being used in each of those classes.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` class members can be used with incomplete types.  The type needs to be complete when `make_shared` is called (or a `shared_ptr` is manually created from a raw pointer), so that should be done in the implementation file after including all relevant headers, not inline in the class.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use forward declarations for shared pointers as well, you just need to forward declare a destructor function object as well.

Header:

```
struct A;
shared_ptr<A> create_A();
```

Impl:

```
struct A { ... };
struct A_destroyer { void operator()(A *p) { delete p; }  };
shared_ptr<A> create_A() { return shared_ptr<A>(new A(), A_destroyer()); }
```

Comment: You do not need that - each class can declare a destructor and define that in a source including the header for the destructed type. (Also, your destroyer looks like a memory leak)

Comment: tohava has giving me the right anwer, thank you tohava

Answer (score 0):

Each class can declare a destructor and define that destructor in a source including the header for the appropriate type destructed by unique/shared pointer. Than a simple forward of that type in the header will do it.

```
#include <memory>

// header B
struct A;
struct B {
    ~B();
    std::shared_ptr<A> a;
};

// header A
struct A {};

// source B
#include "a"
#include "b"
B::~B() {}
```